# Sqoop Imported Failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005 when trying to import Oracle table

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I get the following error when trying to import a table from an Oracle database as a parquet file.

```
 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005
```

This question has already been raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259565/imported-failed-cannot-convert-sql-type-2005-during-importing-clob-data-from), but the proposed solution does not help me.

I am trying to import a table from command line using the following command with parameters in <> filled in with their corresponding value:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>/<service> --username <user>  --password <password> --hive-import --query 'SELECT * FROM <DB>.<table> WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by <ID> --hive-database <HIVE_DB> --hive-table <HIVE_TABLE> --incremental append --check-column <ID> --map-column-hive <ID>=integer --compression-codec=snappy --target-dir=/user/hive/<FOLDER> --as-parquetfile --last-value 0 -m 1`

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am not an expert on the sqooped Oracle database, but it seems to be due to the presence of CLOB data types.
I am running this command on CDH 5.8 with sqoop 1.4.6

Running the job without `--as-parquetfile` results in a sqoop job that seems to get stuck at map 0% reduce 0%.

Comment: try Input parsing arguments: see comment [here](https://reviews.apache.org/r/38554/) -  tht redirects to here.... http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects

Comment: I tried to add some of these already, but they did not help yet. I'll look into it more deeply. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @RonakPatel Which arguments would you provide for this oracle import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `--map-column-java` to map `clob` datatype to Java `String`.

For example, you have a column `C1`. Use:

```
--map-column-java C1=String
```

Check [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_type_mapping) for more details.

Comment: Can you do this is in a more general way so you don't need to specify individual columns?

Comment: @ThijsDieltjens  No there is no other way to provide java mapping.

Comment: Having the map-column-java option seems to help (definitely for DATA types) and makes sure the error disappears. Loading the data however is stuck at 0% map, while without the clob column it finishes within a minute. Do I need  Input parsing arguments like Ronak Patel commented? And if so which of these do I need since the documentation itself does not make it a lot clearer for me.

Comment: Apparantly you need Hive mapping too.  Try `--map-column-hive C1=string` along with java mapping _(assuming corresponding column in Hive is string)_.

Comment: I don't know if I really needed the `--map-column-hive`, but it is now working. Apparently with the CLOB column loading the data just takes a long time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--map-column-java` to map the column type to String. Types in SQL Server 2005, like `datetime`, `varchar(max)`, `bit`, `cblob`, `blob` and others, are not accepted in hive as a valid type.

```
--map-column-java C1=String,C2=String,C3=String
```